.net:in nuget "semantic-kernel",some types of planner can't invoke
This is my code
builder.AddOpenAIChatCompletion(modelId: "gpt-4o", apiKey: openAiKey,
    httpClient: new HttpClient(handler));//at this,i add a new httpclient 
_kernel = kernel.KernelBuild();
        var pluginDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "AiFun", "plugins", "OfficePlugin");
        _kernel.ImportPluginFromPromptDirectory(Path.Combine(pluginDirectoryPath, "SummarizePlugin"));
        _kernel.ImportPluginFromPromptDirectory(Path.Combine(pluginDirectoryPath, "WriterPlugin"));

        _kernel.ImportPluginFromType<MathPlugin>();
       
        planner = new HandlebarsPlanner(new HandlebarsPlannerOptions() { AllowLoops = true });
   
        var plan = await planner.CreatePlanAsync(_kernel, target);
        var result = (await plan.InvokeAsync(_kernel,new KernelArguments())).Trim();

If target is about "math". It can be well done, but if I try that target is about WriterPlugin or SummarizePlugin plan can be created, but it can't be invoked. For a long time, no response. Why?
details:
when target ="5+7+1" ,can receive plan:
{{!-- Step 0: Extract key values --}} 
{{set "value1" 5}} 
{{set "value2" 7}} 
{{set "value3" 1}}

{{!-- Step 1: Add 5 and 7 --}}  
{{set "sum1" (MathPlugin-Add value=value1 amount=value2)}}

{{!-- Step 2: Add the previous sum and 1 --}}  
{{set "finalSum" (MathPlugin-Add value=sum1 amount=value3)}}

{{!-- Step 3: Print the final result --}} 
{{json finalSum}}

and it can be invoked ,result = 13
When target ="give me a poem",can receive plan :
{{!-- Step 1: Set the scenario for the poem --}}

{{set "poemScenario" "a peaceful morning by the lake"}}

{{!-- Step 2: Generate the poem using the WriterPlugin-ShortPoem helper --}}

{{set "generatedPoem" (WriterPlugin-ShortPoem input=poemScenario)}}

{{!-- Step 3: Output the generated poem --}}

{{json generatedPoem}}

But it can't be invoked. Because it's asyn, app is awaiting for response.no error messages and no exception happen.
I found that, to the API, my app send:

{"messages":[{"content":"Generate a short funny poem or limerick to
explain the given event. Be creative and be funny. Let your
imagination run wild.\nEvent:a peaceful morning by the
lake\n","role":"user"}],"max_tokens":60,"temperature":0.5,"top_p":0,"n":1,"presence_penalty":0,"frequency_penalty":0,"model":"gpt-4o"}

And API can receive that:

{"id":"chatcmpl-9axNkvkL1OA9rriIQ5RCbQbwTUTIN","object":"chat.completion","created":1718595100,"model":"gpt-4o","choices":[{"index":0,"message":{"role":"assistant","content":"By the lake on a morning so bright,\nA duck tried to take its first
flight.\nBut it slipped on a log,\nFell right into a frog,\nWho
croaked, "Next time, use a
kite!""},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":"stop"}],"usage":{"prompt_tokens":42,"completion_tokens":44,"total_tokens":86},"system_fingerprint":"fp_f4e629d0a5","code":0,"msg":"ok"}

it's the same of that invoke plugin, but in plan.invoke,no message.
MathPlugin is from Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Plugins.Core
SummarizePlugin and WriterPlugin is from github "https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/tree/main/prompt_template_samples"
